# How can I create a JComboBox that has zero width border?

Tags: swing, layout

I want to display a "table" where a `JLabel` is right justified in column 1 and a component is left justified in column 2 for each row. I've been able to make it look good when the column 2 components are `JLabel`, `JTextField`, and `JCheckBox`. But I'm understandably having trouble with `JComboBox`.

I see two ways (possibly three) to solve the problem.

1. increase the left inset for the non-JComboBox components
2. zero the insets for all components and let the layout manager handle gaps
3. fiddle with the UIManager to zero the JComboBox insets?

The #2 option seemed like an easier approach to understand, implement, and maintain until I tried it. I started with `FormLayout` but since I got the same "misalignment" problems with `GridLayout`, I chose to post the GridLayout version to make it easier to Verify. Please tell me I can get option #2 working without too much trouble or how to make option #3 work.

Below is my [MCV](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.*;

public class TestFrame3 extends JFrame {

    public TestFrame3 () {
        JLabel l1 = new JLabel("l1");     l1.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
        JLabel r1 = new JLabel("r1");     r1.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
        JLabel l2 = new JLabel("l2");     l2.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));

        JComboBox r2 = new JComboBox();   r2.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
        r2.setRenderer(new BasicComboBoxRenderer() {
            @Override
            public Component getListCellRendererComponent (JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
                JComponent comp = (JComponent) super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
                comp.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
                return comp;
            }
        });

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));

        p.add(l1);
        p.add(r1);
        p.add(l2);
        p.add(r2);

        getContentPane().add(p);
        setSize(new Dimension(100, 200));
    }
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        new TestFrame3().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Here's what is displayed, showing the 'r' in 'r1' not lined up with the left-most pixels of the border stroke of the `JComboBox`:

[image]

At Sergiy's prompting, I tested the code on Windows 10 and Fedora 20 and was also unable to reproduce the problem. It makes me [wonder](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-Apple-stopping-support-for-Java-in-Mac-OS-X). Also at his prompting, I tried setting the UI to `BasicComboBoxUI` instead of using the default `com.apple.laf.AquaComboBoxUI` and the alignment problem did not manifest. Unfortunately, that UI is unattractive in a different way.

Comment: Cannot reproduce your problem for Windows. Probably it's a Mac-only issue?

Comment: You can also try to insert the line `r2.setUI(new BasicComboBoxUI());`. But I'm not sure whether this workaround will satisfy you.